# Flask CORS - no Access-control-allow-origin header present on a redirect()

Tags: python, angularjs, flask, flask-restful

I am implementing OAuth Twitter User-sign in (Flask API and Angular)

I keep getting the following error when I click the sign in with twitter button and a pop up window opens:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=r-euFwAAAAAAgJsmAAABTp8VCiE. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I am using the python-Cors packages to handle CORS, and I already have instagram sign in working correctly. 
I believe it has something to do with the response being a redirect but have not been able to correct the problem.

My flask code looks like this:

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='', static_folder=client_path)
cors = CORS(app, allow_headers='Content-Type', CORS_SEND_WILDCARD=True)
app.config.from_object('config')

@app.route('/auth/twitter', methods=['POST','OPTIONS'])
@cross_origin(origins='*', send_wildcard=True)
#@crossdomain(origin='')
def twitter():
    request_token_url = 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token'
    access_token_url = 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token'
    authenticate_url = 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate'

    # print request.headers

    if request.args.get('oauth_token') and request.args.get('oauth_verifier'):
        -- omitted for brevity --
    else:
        oauth = OAuth1(app.config['TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY'],
                       client_secret=app.config['TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET'],
                       callback_uri=app.config['TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL'])
        r = requests.post(request_token_url, auth=oauth)
        oauth_token = dict(parse_qsl(r.text))
        qs = urlencode(dict(oauth_token=oauth_token['oauth_token']))
        return redirect(authenticate_url + '?' + qs)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is not yours. Your client-side application is sending requests to Twitter, so it isn't you that need to support CORS, it is Twitter. But the Twitter API does not currently support CORS, which effectively means that you cannot talk to it directly from the browser.

A common practice to avoid this problem is to have your client-side app send the authentication requests to a server of your own (such as this same Flask application that you have), and in turn the server connects to the Twitter API. Since the server side isn't bound to the CORS requirements there is no problem.

In case you want some ideas, I have written a blog article on doing this type of authentication flow for Facebook and Twitter: http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/oauth-authentication-with-flask

Comment: I forked your repo that is provided in the article you posted. But receive the same error on the client side.   `XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=FozjZwAAAAAAgJsmAAABTqljgg0. No Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: As it stands, the client starts but sending a post request to server of a different domain (Flask api) authorize/twitter, which then returns the twitter redirect, and that is where I see the error message on the client app

Comment: The error that you are showing me suggests the browser is sending a request directly to the Twitter API, so it does not agree with what you are saying. Note that URL https://api.twitter.com/... in the error message. The implementation in my tutorial never sends Ajax requests directly to the provider, all requests go through the Flask application (which I conveniently serve on the same domain as the client side app).

Comment: If my Angular client app and Flask api are on different domains, is there a way to get this to work? -- ( I did get it working with your example app btw, thanks)

Comment: @DanielGaeta if you are relying all the auth requests through your API, then just add CORS support in your Flask API project, and that will enable your Angular app to talk to the Flask API, regardless of where it is hosted. The Flask API is then free to contact the Twitter API on behalf of the Angular app.

Comment: @DanielGaeta where you able to get this working? I'm having the same issue. It looks like you added CORS support in the code above with `CORS(app, allow_headers='Content-Type', CORS_SEND_WILDCARD=True) `

Comment: @Miguel I believe the authorize function is braking in this setup because of the redirect in on the api (server side).  It seems like the api server needs to send back the authorize_url to the app and then the app would send the request to the social website (using the authorize_url) which would then "somehow" send a replay to the api server to create or login the user but now I have lost my flow because the app is not going to know this happened.